# How do the odds of producing Uranium-235 and Uranium-238 work?

Tags: factorio

I've finally got a nuclear reactor up and running.  In order to do this, you need both Uranium-235 and Uranium-238 to create a Uranium fuel cell (as well as iron plates, but that part is easy).  To make both Uranium-235 and Uranium-238, you need to use a [centrifuge](https://wiki.factorio.com/Centrifuge).

From observing the centrifuge as it works, it produces **much** more Uranium-238 than Uranium-235.  This is having a major impact on producing the fuel cells needed to power my reactor since the production of Uranium-235 is so little.

What are the odds of producing both Uranium-235 and Uranium-238? Is it random with a heavier weight towards Uranium-238 or is there a defined odds such as 100:1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [version 0.15.8](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=46505) the game displays these probabilities to enough precision (using percentage notation) to see usable values for the *uranium processing* recipe, but if you're still interested, the exact definition can be found in the game's files. `data/base/prototypes/recipe/recipe.lua` contains:

```
  {
    name = "uranium-235",
    probability = 0.007,
    amount = 1
  },
  {
    name = "uranium-238",
    probability = 0.993,
    amount = 1
  }
```

For each batch of ore you process, the result is independently selected according to those probabilities. [*On average*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) you will get 7 <sup>235</sup>U and 993 <sup>238</sup>U out of every 1000, but [there is no guarantee of exact numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy).

Since this is much, much larger than the ratio needed for fuel production (1:19), you must do something about the extra <sup>238</sup>U.

1. First, create a generous storage buffer (I recall needing about four steel chests) to keep <sup>238</sup>U from clogging things up until you have a better solution.
2. Research the technology **Kovarex enrichment process**. This will allow you to convert <sup>238</sup>U into <sup>235</sup>U, which will not only solve your ratio problem but also allow for **immensely more efficient use of uranium ore** (and fewer centrifuges).

   Note that the actual enrichment process requires that you have at minimum 40 <sup>235</sup>U as a catalyst which you keep circulating, and preferably more to get the cycle going better despite items sitting idle in belts and input slots. (Players have come up with a wide variety of designs for this.) Therefore, it is wise to save up some <sup>235</sup>U early on and not turn it all into fuel, so you don't have to wait again to bootstrap your enrichment.
3. (Optional:) Research the technology **Uranium ammo**. This allows you to use extra <sup>238</sup>U for another purpose. (The technology **Atomic bomb** uses  <sup>235</sup>U so it is not helpful here.)

Comment: I saw the Kovarex enrichment process, but haven't obtained it yet.  Still have you to start making productivity science packs since they are rather difficult now.  7 out of 1000 are terrible odds :(

Comment: If you check (just did myself), those numbers (0.7% and 99.3%) are the same as in naturally occuring uranium deposits.

Of course, this isn't actually Earth, so... maybe it should be random.  Actually, it should be.

Comment: I've also noticed that either when you build the centrifuge or tell it what you want it to make (I don't remember which), it now lists the odds of each Uranium type.  Fairly certain that was added after I posted this question - otherwise I probably wouldn't have asked.

Comment: @TimmyJim Yep, that was changed in [version 0.15.8](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=46505).

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard The natural isotope ratios aren't random but stem from the nucleosynthesis processes that created the matter the planet is made of. They shouldn't be too different on other habitable planets.

Comment: @AndreKR Actually, they only depend on the *age* of the matter the planet is made out of. The ratio could easily be both much higher and much lower on other planets. Even if you assume all supernova material gets used to make planets after the same amount of time (not true), you can have variations of billions of years in the age of the planet itself. What you're saying is more true for stable elements (at least for very rough proportions), but uranium in particular comes almost exclusively from neutron star mergers and spontaneously decays over time - the ratio changes with time.

Comment: @Luaan, it also depends on whether or not the deposit experienced the right conditions to become a natural nuclear fission reactor, which _did_ happen on Earth, almost 2 billion years ago in Africa. Because some of the 235-U was used up, the ratio there is closer to 0.6%.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_nuclear_fission_reactor